# Escaping an apostrophe in Sqldf with R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a dataframe *mergeTest* which have a column *Name* with apostrophes on few values,

So I'm looping through it to divide values which denominator are contained in the table *nbrToDivide*

```
test1 <- sqldf(c(paste('UPDATE mergeTest SET Value = Value/',nbrToDivide[i],
            ' WHERE `Year` =',nbrToDivide$`Year`[i],
            ' AND UPPER(Name) = \'',nbrToDivide$Name[i],sep=""),
    'SELECT * from mergeTestt'))
```

The problem is when the value of *UPPER(Name)* contains an apostrophe in it, it will interprete it and return an error.

I tried to use **gsub** with **grepl** but it adds two backslashes to my names so I dunno if there is a way to deal with it or should I just suppress the apostrophe in my two datraframes ?

Comment: have you tried `\\'` instead of `\'`?

Answer (score 4):

Double the single quote.  Here is an example:

```
> sqldf("select 'O''Brian' Name")
     Name
1 O'Brian
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing one single quote with two single quotes will fix this as in :

```
"SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE FieldName = 'QueryString''s Value'"
```